# cygwin xterm not responding to keyboard

Tags: cygwin, xterm, rxvt

My cygwin xterm is not responding to the keyboard.

I am able to run rxvt, but when I start other X applications I have the same problem.

From the rxvt command prompt, I get the following:

```
$ xterm
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: :0
```

The contents of my XWin.0.log are:

```
$ cat XWin.0.log 
Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.5.3.0 (10503000)

Contact: cygwin-xfree@cygwin.com

XWin was started with the following command line:

/usr/bin/XWin -multiwindow -clipboard -silent-dup-error 

ddxProcessArgument - Initializing default screens
winInitializeDefaultScreens - w 1440 h 900
winInitializeDefaultScreens - Returning

Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
        If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
        and start again.

GetWindowProp - pWin or name was NULL
GetWindowProp - pWin or name was NULL
GetWindowProp - pWin or name was NULL
GetWindowProp - pWin or name was NULL
GetWindowProp - pWin or name was NULL
GetWindowProp - pWin or name was NULL
GetWindowProp - pWin or name was NULL
GetWindowProp - pWin or name was NULL
```

Removing  /tmp/.X0-lock didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-i-cant-type-anything).

1. First stop the server by right-clicking on the X icon in the system tray and choosing exit.
2. Run the startxwin.bat file that is located in /usr/bin.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the back of my mind is saying "turn off Num Lock".

I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off Num Lock solved my problem. I was opening an xterm on a remote system running AIX, and the only key that seemed to do anything was the space bar, which typed a space. Turning off Num Lock allowed the other keys to work. (The AIX version of emacs did not have a problem.) I assume it must be special treatment of the Num Lock key in AIX 4.3 version of /usr/bin/X11/xterm

[According to the Cygwin X FAQ:](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#numlock-modifier)

> 8.14. Why do some menus not work if Num-Lock is on?
>
> The problem are programs which treat Num-Lock as modifier similar to Control. The programs expect a plain click but received some strange Num-Lock-Click combination and can't associate this with the action "open menu".